# Best subset selection includes predictor with high p-value

Tags: predictive-modeling, feature-selection

I'm trying to use subset selection to find out the best model according to AIC. However, it is recommending a variable with a p-value > .9. My guess is that this is because the subset selection function is prioritizing AIC over the significance of variables. Is this correct?

If I include this variable, what do I have to worry about? I've tried including it versus excluding it. When I include it, the overall prediction accuracy goes down, but the true positive rate goes up and the false positive goes down. When I exclude it, overall accuracy goes up, but true positive goes down and false positive goes up. For my problem, having a high true positive and low false positive is particularly important. I should also mention that my data is very unbalanced. I'm thinking of including it for the sake of my priorities. Thoughts?